# Blender show array instances as wireframe

Tags: modifiers, 3d-view

I have an array in my scene and my computer has some trouble showing them in the viewport. Is there any way that I can get the instances to show up as a wireframe mesh or maybe even a point cloudor bounds?

[image: Here is what it looks like]

[image: what I want it to look like]

Comment: AFAIK, no. any special reason you want the original to be solid?

Comment: I just want to ease up the viewport. At render time i want all of them shown as proper models. IN thee viewport however I only want to see the original as shaded and the rest as wireframe.

Comment: In this case you may be better off using dupli-faces or dupli-verts (better performance)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @user320 another option is applying the array modifier, `P` > *separate by loose parts* then linking the object data. (you could set each object to a wire draw type)

Comment: then they would no longer be part of the array though. At each of them would take up more ram at render time

Comment: @user320 I might be wrong, but doesn't linking the object data have all the object reference one datablock?

Comment: I think you're right actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some options. Create a linked duplicate with <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>. Give it a copy location and copy rotation constraint with your actual object as target or just parent it. Disable rendering and selectability for your fake object in the outliner.Set the object *Type* of the array object to *Wireframe* or *Boundbox* in the *Display* panel of the *Object Properties*.

Now you have a fake object that won't bother you much and the whole array set to wireframe. Not ideal if you want to edit the object but going into *Local Mode* with <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> temporarily gets rid of that, too. Or you don't make it unselectable and hide it.

Or you can put a Decimate or Remesh modifier on top of it all that doesn't get rendered. That way your Polycount gets reduced as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another way might be:

1. Apply the array modifier(s).
2. In edit mode, <kbd>P</kbd>*> Separate by loose parts*.
3. With all the objects selected, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*> Origin to geometry*
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Make Links > Object Data*.
5. Deselect one of the objects, set the *Display type* in *Properties > Object Data* to *Wire*, right click and select *Copy to selected*:

[image]

Now you can still edit the original and have your edits copied.